# JMS deserialize with XML List, xpath in SimpleXmlElement not working

Tags: php, xml, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm trying to deserialize this XML

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <InformationDisclosureResponse xmlns="http://ASD.pl">
        <DisclosureReport>
            <Number>U/123</Number>
            <Created>2017-10-03T15:00:50+02:00</Created>
            <SearchCriterion>
                <NonConsumerIdentityNumber>
                    <TaxId>123123123</TaxId>
                </NonConsumerIdentityNumber>
                <AuthorizationDateSpecified>false</AuthorizationDateSpecified>
                <ActAuthorizationDateSpecified>false</ActAuthorizationDateSpecified>
                <SearchType>RegularSearch</SearchType>
                <SearchCriterionType>TaxId</SearchCriterionType>
            </SearchCriterion>
            <Requester>
                <LegalPerson>
                    <Name>Test</Name>
                    <IdentityNumber>
                        <TaxId>123123123</TaxId>
                    </IdentityNumber>
                    <SeatAddress>
                        <Line>asd 72</Line>
                    </SeatAddress>
                </LegalPerson>
                <LoginFullName>ASD</LoginFullName>
            </Requester>
            <Summary>
                <InformationCount>2</InformationCount>
                <TotalArrears>
                    <Amount>123321.52</Amount>
                    <Currency>PLN</Currency>
                </TotalArrears>
            </Summary>
            <PositiveInformationSummary>
                <ProvidersCount>0</ProvidersCount>
            </PositiveInformationSummary>
            <Report>
                <ObligationInformations>
                    <ObligationInformation category="0">
                        <Debtor>
                            <Entrepreneur>
                                <Name>ASDASD</Name>
                                <AddressForMail>
                                    <Line>ASD ASD</Line>
                                </AddressForMail>
                                <SeatAddress>
                                    <Line>ASD123</Line>
                                </SeatAddress>
                                <NonConsumerIdentityNumber>
                                    <TaxId>123123123</TaxId>
                                </NonConsumerIdentityNumber>
                                <FirstName>ASD</FirstName>
                                <Surname>ASD</Surname>
                            </Entrepreneur>
                        </Debtor>
                        <Provider>
                            <LegalPerson>
                                <Name>ASD</Name>
                                <IdentityNumber>
                                    <TaxId>123123123</TaxId>
                                </IdentityNumber>
                                <SeatAddress>
                                    <Line>Asd, asd</Line>
                                </SeatAddress>
                                <RegistrationNumber>123123</RegistrationNumber>
                                <RegistryName>ASD</RegistryName>
                                <Regon>123123</Regon>
                                <Ekd>123S/07</Ekd>
                            </LegalPerson>
                        </Provider>
                        <Title>Fd-dasd</Title>
                        <Type>Invoice</Type>
                        <PaymentDate>2017-04-20T00:00:00+02:00</PaymentDate>
                        <NoObjections>true</NoObjections>
                        <CallSent>2017-05-29T00:00:00+02:00</CallSent>
                        <Debt>
                            <Amount>123.80</Amount>
                            <Currency>PLN</Currency>
                        </Debt>
                        <Arrears>
                            <Amount>321.80</Amount>
                            <Currency>PLN</Currency>
                        </Arrears>
                    </ObligationInformation>
                </ObligationInformations>
            </Report>
        </DisclosureReport>
    </InformationDisclosureResponse>
</s:Body>
```

With class

```
    class ReportResponse{
/**
 * @var DisclosureReport
 *
 * @JMS\Type("DisclosureReport")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("DisclosureReport")
 */
public $disclosureReport;
//geter
}
```

.

```
class DisclosureReport{
/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @JMS\Type("string")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("Number")
 */
public $number;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @JMS\Type("string")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("Created")
 */
public $created;

/**
 * @var SearchCriterion|null
 *
 * @JMS\Type("SearchCriterion")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("SearchCriterion")
 */
public $searchCriterion;

/**
 * @var Requester|null
 *
 * @JMS\Type("Requester")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("Requester")
 */
public $requester;

/**
 * @var Summary|null
 *
 * @JMS\Type("Summary")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("Summary")
 */
public $summary;

/**
 * @var PositiveInformationSummary|null
 *
 * @JMS\Type("PositiveInformationSummary")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("PositiveInformationSummary")
 */
public $positiveInformationSummary;

/**
 * @var Report|null
 *
 * @JMS\Type("Report")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("Report")
 */
public $report;
//geters
}
```

.

```
class Report{
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection|null
 *
 * @JMS\Type("ArrayCollection<ObligationInformation>")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("ObligationInformations")
 * @JMS\XmlList(entry="ObligationInformation")
 */
public $obligationInformations;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection|null
 *
 * @JMS\Type("ArrayCollection<PaidObligationInformation>")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("PaidObligationInformations")
 * @JMS\XmlList(entry="PaidObligationInformation")
 */
public $paidObligationInformations;
}
```

And every thing parsing ok, but ArrayCollection with ObligationInformation doesn't. Still getting empty ArrayCollection, even with `array` type.

Trying with out attribute category, with different version of `JMS/Serializer-bundle` (current I use `1.1.0` with jms/serializer `1.5.0`) with no success.

When debugging I found that here https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/1.5.0/src/JMS/Serializer/XmlDeserializationVisitor.php#L158 I get empty array. `$entityName` is `ObligationInformation`, like here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f6213c5937f8e1cc78e46c710ae1a0f009338d5 in sandbox PHP, but in this I get data.

When do it what is in sandbox in my app, result is the same like in sandbox. But in this JMS file with `$data` like sandbox `$xml`, I get empty array why?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you've got the wrong XML namespace defined in `<InformationDisclosureResponse xmlns="http://ASD.pl">`
element. Try to deserialize without it and it should do the trick.

Comment: This namespace was purposely change, but I forgot change it in class. I use correct namespace, so it is not solved me issue Siadul.

Answer (score 0):

I found temporary solution for this problem.

In JMS tag `XmlList` define enrty as `child::*` now it's look like:

```
@JMS\XmlList(entry="child::*")
```

And it's works! But it's work around.. But still..